# RAILS 6 has_and_belongs_to_many >> join_table << does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I want to use a join_table between two many to many relations.

**student -> join_table <- teacher**

MODEL definition :

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, join_table: map_student_teacher
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students, join_table: map_student_teacher
end
```

Migration Definition :

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :students do |t|
      t.string : student_name
    end
  end
end

class CreateTeachers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
     create_table :teachers do |t|
       t.string : teacher_name
     end
  end
end


class CreateStudentsTeachersJoinTable < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
     create_table :map_student_teacher, id: false do |t|
       t.belongs_to :student, index: true
       t.belongs_to :teacher, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

Now I have a seeds.rb file to initialize the students names.

```
students_defaults = ["hans","otto","paul","elsa"]

students_defaults.each do |name|
  Student.create(student_name: name) 
end
```

When I load the seed by `rails db:seed`
I got this error message:

```
rails aborted!
NameError: undefined local variable or method `map_student_teacher' for Student (call 'Student.connection' to establish a connection):Class
/home/sven/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/activerecord-6.0.2.2/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:22:in `method_missing'
```

What is going wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model classes it should say `join_table: :map_student_teacher`. Note the extra colon to make map_student_teacher into a symbol. Without that Ruby is trying to look inside a local called map_student_teacher, which is undefined.

```
class Student < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :teachers, join_table: :map_student_teacher
end

class Teacher < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :students, join_table: :map_student_teacher
end
```

If this is ugly to you, you can also use the older `:join_table => :map_student_teacher` syntax.